# CSS Animation: different cubic-bezier

Tags: css, css-animations

I have a simple animation which I want to “overshoot” when it gets to the end. Then it should reverse and “overshoot” at the other end.

The code looks something like this:

```
h1 {
    animation-name: test 3000ms infinite alternate;
    animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.300, -0.530, 0.765, 1.530);
}
@keyframes test {
    from {
        transform: translate(0,0);
    }
    to {
        transform: translate(100px,0);
    }
}
```

The problem is that the animation also “undershoots” at the beginning of each iteration.

How do I apply a an `animation-timing-function` in one direction only?, and a different one in the other direction?

Thanks

Comment: Just curious, why not change the keyframes itself to produce the effect instead of using cubic bezier timing function? I mean you can do negative translation.

Comment: @Harry Mainly because I didn’t think of it. I did manage to get the right effect by changing the direction to `forward`, dumping the `cubic-bezier` and replacing it with `ease-in-out`, and adding extra key frames to reverse the process. It works, but it’s more coding, and it would be interesting to know whether there is a slicker solution. Thanks.

Comment: [This](https://jsfiddle.net/ar7ej8v4/) seems to work but its only a marginal improvement. I am not posting as answer because I feel it is still not 100% what you originally wanted. Let me know in case you are OK with having that as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Value range of cubic-bezier is 0-1,

> **cubic-bezier(n,n,n,n):**
>   Define your own values in the cubic-bezier function Possible values
>   are numeric values from 0 to 1

How about set your requirement in percentage for infinite as well,

You can control its speed by assigning value to respective percentage.

```
div {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: red;
    position :relative;
    -webkit-animation: mymove 5s infinite;
    animation: mymove 5s infinite;
}

@-webkit-keyframes mymove {
    0%   {top: 0px;}
    25%  {top: 200px;}
    75%  {top: 50px}
    100% {top: 0px;}
}

@keyframes mymove {
    0%   {top: 0px;}
    25%  {top: 200px;}
    75%  {top: 50px}
    100% {top: 0px;}
}
```

Comment: Nope, negative values and values greater than 1 are perfectly valid for the ordinates - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/timing-function

Comment: FYI as of recently, animation no longer requires a prefix. See [animation](http://caniuse.com/#search=animation)

Answer (score 0):

When you are setting different keyframes, the timing function applies to each movement between keyframe and keyframe.

so, setting a middle point at 50% will get your effect

```css
h1 {
    display: inline-block;
}

h1:hover {
    animation: test 3000ms;
    animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.15, 0.32, 0.55, 1.35);
}


@keyframes test {
      0% { transform: translate(  0px,0);}
     50% { transform: translate(100px,0);}
    100% { transform: translate(  0px,0);}
}
```

```html
<h1>TEST</h1>
```

Also, if you set the animation in a way that can be triggered (in the hover, as I have done, for instance) then you can use Chrome dev tools to inspect it.

[image: dev tools]